# Freenas is slow - network @ 400MB/sec, disk @ 150MB/sec

Tags: iscsi, network-attached-storage, truenas

I have a 16 core virtualization FreeNAS 11.3-U4.1 instance running on Hyper-V with 32GB of RAM with a 18TB iscsi target on DELL T630 server grade hardware.

HDD are on IT mode from the RAID card, so presented to the FreeNAS box as individual drives.

I do not have any dedupe running, default compression only.

The windows share is running ReFS as a iscsi initiator on Windows Server 2019 and is not full only 1TB or so, used for transferring test movie files.

From multiple machines tested (one at a time), it is initially fast on any transfer - read or write @ 130MB/sec - but then after a minute or so slows down to 40Mbps and at times even keeps stalling.

Network tests are fast both internally via machines on same box and also external machines:

```
root@freenas[~]# iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
^Ciperf3: interrupt - the server has terminated
root@freenas[~]# iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 192.168.69.139, port 49435
[  5] local 192.168.69.4 port 5201 connected to 192.168.69.139 port 49437
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   105 MBytes   878 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   111 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-10.00  sec   339 KBytes   955 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   933 Mbits/sec                  receiver
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 192.168.69.5, port 50601
[  5] local 192.168.69.4 port 5201 connected to 192.168.69.5 port 50602
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   392 MBytes  3.29 Gbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   407 MBytes  3.41 Gbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   426 MBytes  3.57 Gbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   430 MBytes  3.60 Gbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   413 MBytes  3.46 Gbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   429 MBytes  3.60 Gbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   372 MBytes  3.12 Gbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   429 MBytes  3.60 Gbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   424 MBytes  3.56 Gbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   425 MBytes  3.56 Gbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-10.00  sec   125 KBytes  2.29 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
```

**CPU load via top is minimal:**

```
last pid: 15377;  load averages:  1.15,  0.90,  1.06    up 0+12:42:50  03:48:22
44 processes:  1 running, 43 sleeping
CPU:  0.1% user,  0.0% nice, 15.7% system,  0.0% interrupt, 84.2% idle
Mem: 14M Active, 488M Inact, 1060M Laundry, 28G Wired, 1584M Free
ARC: 25G Total, 852M MFU, 19G MRU, 4773M Anon, 580M Header, 75M Other
     20G Compressed, 23G Uncompressed, 1.12:1 Ratio
Swap: 6144M Total, 46M Used, 6097M Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
  104 root         41  20    0   329M   258M kqread  5   3:15   0.77% python3.7
15347 root          1  20    0  7892K  3452K CPU5    5   0:00   0.16% top
 1917 www           1  20    0 30920K 10268K kqread  6   0:01   0.03% nginx
   93 root          1  20    0  9164K  5548K select  7   0:04   0.02% devd
 5597 root          8  20    0 40284K 17892K select  6   1:25   0.00% rrdcached
 1323 root          1  20    0 12484K 12580K select  2   0:02   0.00% ntpd
 1522 root          1  20    0  9012K  5024K select  5   0:01   0.00% zfsd
 1433 root          1  20    0   127M   105M kqread  2   0:03   0.00% uwsgi-3.7
 5622 root         11  20    0   354M   261M nanslp  7   6:57   0.00% collectd
```

**zpools are below:**

```
root@freenas[~]# zpool list -v
NAME                                     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
freenas-boot                             110G  1.25G   109G        -         -   0%     1%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
  da0p2                                  110G  1.25G   109G        -         -   0%     1%
pool1                                   32.5T  2.60T  29.9T        -         -   1%     7%  1.00x  ONLINE  /mnt
  raidz2                                32.5T  2.60T  29.9T        -         -   1%     7%
    gptid/e7aba92d-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
    gptid/ea0339c1-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
    gptid/eadd3d73-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
    gptid/eb18ed64-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
    gptid/eb80f3cc-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
    gptid/eb99fe09-dc27-11ea-b1e2-00155d450302      -      -      -        -     -      -      -
```

**using root@freenas[~]# ./solnet-array-test-v2.sh i can see (the write is showing will take 467 minutes, i am sure write speeds are OK as initially they are fast):**

```
Disk    Disk Size  MB/sec %ofAvg
------- ---------- ------ ------
da0       130048MB    658    268 ++FAST++
da1      5723166MB    204     83 --SLOW--
da2      5723166MB    176     72 --SLOW--
da3      5723166MB    164     67 --SLOW--
da4      5723166MB    161     66 --SLOW--
da5      5723166MB    186     76 --SLOW--
da6      5723166MB    167     68 --SLOW--

Performing initial parallel array read
Wed Aug 12 04:06:35 PDT 2020
The disk da0 appears to be 130048 MB.
Disk is reading at about 1075 MB/sec
This suggests that this pass may take around 2 minutes

                   Serial Parall % of
Disk    Disk Size  MB/sec MB/sec Serial
------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
da0       130048MB    658      0      0 --SLOW--
da1      5723166MB    204    204    100
da2      5723166MB    176    164     93
da3      5723166MB    164    166    101
da4      5723166MB    161    159     99
```

To add, Windows Storage Spaces with the same hardware is @ 150MB/s constant (pretty much what I am seeing above with the test), *but* without the slowdown after 1 minute to 30-50MB/sec that i am seeing in actual use of Freenas.

Any other diagnostics i would need to run or ideas on what this could be?

Comment: What is your network configuration? I'd had an issues with network throughput being slow on Hyper-V VMs, after I did PCIe SR-IOV to the VM my setup gone faster. I was testing CentOS VM, though.

Answer (score 2):

FreeNAS and the whole ZFS on BSD kernel story is dying, get Ubuntu and ZoL, there’s much wider community coverage and better hardware support either way.